# update data when applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iphone app .so i load and parse HTML data,thats all.but when the app  EnterBackground i want to update the results of live matches and show an alert like the 
below image:

[image]

so how i can do that? is with notification?.
and sorry of my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Push Notification, learn how to use them from the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: thank you.is this work if not my web server from where i get the data? .

Comment: If you are obtaining the information from some other service such as Yahoo! Sports or ESPN, you will be required to write a middle server which will be the "Provider" in the diagrams from that documentation. Your "Provider" would be responsible for polling the service you are getting the match information from, once it decides something is interesting enough to notify the user it is responsible for telling the APNS, the APNS will then push the notification to subscribed users.

Comment: no,i am obtaining the data from web site do not support this kind of notification.

Comment: That is why you would need to write a server that sits in the middle to act as the Provider, as described.